# How can i configure a client side data AG Grid table where the child rows can come from a separate API call?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a table with employers. The goal is when I open the row of an employer that I can see the history of role changes in the subrows below. These 'version history child rows' should come from a seperate backend call.

What I would like to achieve is that this table is loaded client side (so not using the server side configuration).

I was trying to use the treeData approach. When opening a row it will push the correct childrow data in the general rowdata and open the row.

The problem is that the expand/collapse icon is not displayed if there are no initial child rows. And I want to retrieve them only after expanding a row.

How can I configure the AG-grid to achieve this functionality ?

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/k3FIchyY4Ead3p5S?open=main.js&preview

Example code:

```
  // Will come from an API call
  const rowData = [
    {
      orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers'],
      jobTitle: 'CEO',
    },
        {
      orgHierarchy: ['Jos Peeters'],
      jobTitle: 'CEO',
    },
    // Collapse/Expand icons are removed once there are no initial child rows
    // Uncommenting this shows te expand icons
    // I would like them to always be visible
    // {
    //   orgHierarchy: ['Jos Peeters', 'Edited'],
    //   jobTitle: 'Exec. Vice President'
    // },
  ];


// I want to open the history of the selected row by pushing this entry in the rowData
 const expandChildRows = (params) => {
    rowData.push( {
      orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers', 'Edited'],
      jobTitle: 'Exec. Vice President',
    })
    params.node.setExpanded(true);
  };


const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // we're using the auto group column by default!
    { field: 'jobTitle' },
    { field: 'employmentType' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
    headerName: 'Organisation Hierarchy',
    minWidth: 300,
    cellRendererParams: {
      suppressCount: true,
    },
  },
  rowData,
  treeData: true, // enable Tree Data mode
  animateRows: true,
  groupDefaultExpanded: -1, // expand all groups by default
  getDataPath: (data) => {
    return data.orgHierarchy;
  },
  onRowClicked: expandChildRows
};
```

Comment: are you trying to implement [Master/Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-grids/)?

Comment: no, because i have the same row structure for the child rows, it will also show the changes that were made on every cell

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your child rows correctly to the grid. Your grid data is never being updated. Change your `expandChildRows` function to the following:

```
const expandChildRows = (params) => {
  console.log('here')
  const row = {
    orgHierarchy: ['Erica Rogers', 'Edited'],
    jobTitle: 'Exec. Vice President',
  };

  gridOptions.rowData.push(row);
  params.api.setRowData(gridOptions.rowData);

  params.node.setExpanded(true);
};
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/oxrfAwy0AYrA8Wau?open=main.js).

Comment: this works indeed but u still don't see the collapse/expand icon initially

Comment: that's because you're only calling the `expandChildRows` function when a row is clicked.

Comment: how can I make the icons visible at all times? even when it has no child rows yet?

Comment: you'd need to add some data for the hierarchy tree, even dummy/empty data rows for the icon to show.